# Do we want accepted answers on our site to be unpinned from the top?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, votos, respuesta-aceptada

On Stack Overflow, accepted answers [have been unpinned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/643262) from the top. This means that, when using the standard "Votes" sort, answers will be sorted only by vote score (upvotes minus downvotes). The accepted answer will appear at its corresponding position based on its vote score, instead of the previous behavior of being always at the top. Part of the motivation seems to be that sometimes accepted answers become obsolete as programming languages evolve, and new, up-to-date answers had no chance of making it to the top.

In the announcement on Meta, Nicolas Chabanovsky (from SE staff) asks

> **Would you like to have the accepted answer unpinned on your site?**

So what are your thoughts on this? Should we ask for unpinned accepted answers on Spanish.SE, or should we leave them pinned to the top?

I have added two answers with the two options: pin the accepted answer, or do not pin it. While written feedback is most welcome in the form of answers or comments, you can also vote on your preferred option if you want to give your opinion anonymously.

---

### Update:

At the deadline of October 11, 2021 at 23:59:59 UTC, the option of keeping the pin had **7 votes** and the option of unpinning had **0 votes**. Therefore, we are **keeping the accepted answer pinned to the top**. I reported this [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/643262).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The accepted answer should stay pinned to the top

Upvote this answer if you want to keep the current behavior, where the accepted answer is pinned to the top.

Comment: There is no certainty that the highest voted answer is in fact the best and the accepted answer did meet the needs of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

### The accepted answer should NOT be pinned to the top

Upvote this answer if you want to change the current behavior and have the accepted answer **not** be pinned to the top.